# Kohana ORM - How can I do this?

Tags: php, mysql, orm, activerecord, kohana

Having never worked with ORM before I thought I would give it a try today, I've come across my first problem that I don't know how to solve (due to my lack of understanding how ORM really works.)

Say I have three tables: Languages, Codes, and a pivot table Codes_Languages. These all have properly defined relationships in the models.

Now, to echo all the names of the languages, I could go like this:

```
$languages = ORM::factory('languages')->find_all();
foreach ($languages as $language)
{
  echo $language->name, '<br />';
}
```

If I want to echo all the names of codes within a particular language, I could go like this:

```
$language = ORM::factory('languages', 1);
foreach ($language->codes as $code)
{
  echo $code->title, ' ', $code->description;
}
```

But how about if I need to do this: Retrieve the latest five codes (ordered by DESC on code.time_posted) in each language?

```
$languages = ORM::factory('languages')->find_all();
???$languages->codes = ORM->order_by('time_posted', 'desc')->limit(5);???
foreach ($languages as $language)
{
  echo $language->name, '<br />';
  foreach ($language->codes as $code)
  {
    echo $code->name, ' ', $code->description;
  }
}
```

I've placed question marks around some pseudo-code which I think explains what I'm trying to do. I've recently converted from CodeIngiter because I think Kohana is a bit more well thought out, however the docs seem lacking and I couldn't find out how to do what I needed.

Any guidance would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: I've never used Kohana's ORM, but from reading [the documentation](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/orm), it seems like you need something like this:

```
ORM::factory('languages')->orderby('time_posted', 'DESC')->find_all(5);
```

You can use nearly all Kohana's [query builder methods](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/database/builder) like `orderby`, `join` etc. on the ORM object to do more complex queries.

(As far as ORMs for PHP go, [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) is about as good as it gets. It should [integrate nicely](http://www.mapledesign.co.uk/code/kohana-doctrine/) with Kohana, or any other framework for that matter.)

Answer (score 0):

ORM in Kohana only works if you follow this conditions :

1. The table name must be in plural (like 'languages', wich you already have done);
2. The table must have an id with auto increment (required);
3. You must create a Model that extends ORM class (this one not in plural, 'language'), like :

   class Language_Model extends ORM { }

You can latter post some additional parameters to the class above, following kohana's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$languages = ORM::factory('languages')->find_all();

foreach ($languages as $language)
{
  echo $language->name, '<br />';
  foreach ($language->order_by('time_posted', 'desc')->limit(5)->codes as $code)
  {
    echo $code->name, ' ', $code->description;
  }
}
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work; I've been using Kohana's ORM for a few weeks now.